# Dialog over modal using React Native Paper?

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

I'm using React Native Paper library and I have a Modal and Dialog, I want to dialog to appear in front of the modal... is there a way to do this?

If there's no way I would have to code the structure of a dialog on my own using a Modal and I'd rather not do that...

Thanks

Comment: have you found a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem and I solved it by using both `react-native-paper` and `react-native`'s Modal.

- `react-native`: 0.63.2
- `react-native-paper`: 2.16.0

```js
import {Modal as RNModal} from 'react-native';
import {Modal, Portal} from 'react-native-paper';

return (
<Portal>
   <Modal>
      <View>
        ...content for the view
      </View>
      <RNModal visible={props.visible} transparent={true}>
        <Dialog visible={props.visible} onDismiss={props.onDismiss}>
        ...content for dialog
        </Dialog>
      <RNModal>
   </Modal>
</Portal>
);
```

`RNModal` causes the inner dialog to always be on top.